# Error in iterating over a pandas dataframe created from a excel file column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading an `excel` file column into a `pandas` `dataframe`. This is the code I have written for this:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('address.xlsx').parse('sheet1')  

x = df['Address']
print(x)
```

Output of above code is:

```
0                         Via abc che - 66110 Chi
1                 Via vivo, 44\n65125 Paris (PR)
2                 Via vivo, 44\n65125 Pesc (PI)
3            Contrada contra\n64100 Term (PI)
4                    Via Mvico\n75025 Poli (PR)
```

There is only item in each row, which is an `address`. Now what I want to do is iterate through each row of this `dataframe`, get the address and then extract zip code out of that address. I wrote this code for this:

```
for index ,row in x:
    reg = re.compile('^.*(?P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$')
    match = reg.match(row[0])
    fitered_match = match.groupdict().zipcode  
    print(fitered_match)
```

When I execute this I get error as `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

I am unable to understand:

1. Why this error is coming?
2. Is my logic to extract zip code out of the address is correct?

Comment: Well, I would not recommend using a loop here, but to get it to work you need `for index, row in enumerate(x):`

Comment: @rahlf23 what would be an ideal approach to achieve the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extract()`:

```
df['Zip Code'] = df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})')
```

Yields:

```
                            Address Zip Code
0           Via abc che - 66110 Chi    66110
1    Via vivo, 44\n65125 Paris (PR)    65125
2     Via vivo, 44\n65125 Pesc (PI)    65125
3  Contrada contra\n64100 Term (PI)    64100
4        Via Mvico\n75025 Poli (PR)    75025
```

In your original code, the reason you are receiving the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` is because you did not use `enumerate(x)`, as you are attempting to iterate both indices and values.